# Can an edit window be opened manually similar to the Edit Top 200 Rows option in Sql Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ide, ssms

This screen is so useful in development. Is there a way to have all query windows behave like this one? It seems special and is only invoked if you select the "Edit Top 200 Rows" option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a **REALLY TERRIBLE IDEA™** to edit data in SQL Server this way.  It may be *easier*, but it will leas to issues with consistency and/or invalid/miskeyed data.  If you put all your inserts into scripts, you have version control and duplicability of your data.  If you ad-hoc key everything, you are likely to lose all your data without being able to remake it as it was.

Comment: Understood. The main driver for this was editing a third party app that has its config in a table with key/value pairs, and I was getting irritated writing an update script every time I wanted to change something. I would say in this case, your concerns are less risky, but in most other cases, absolutely valid.

Comment: This answer is not useful. Without knowing a whole lot more about my use case and situation, you simply ***cannot*** tell me that what I want to do is a "really terrible idea", at least not without coming across as arrogant. (Do people really work this way? You need to add one row to a table, so you write an effing script for it? How do you have time for anything?)

Comment: @Martha Yes editing rows is pretty much always a terrible idea. 1) it's not reproducible. 2) It's imprecise. 3) It's not auditable. 4) It's not a great burden to spend 30 seconds scripting it out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a way to make a query window behave like the "Edit" window, but there's a way to make the "Edit" window behave like a query window (and possibly achieving what you want):

I'm guessing at why you want to do this... but say for example you want to do this so that you can filter records down to a subset of the whole table:  Once you've opened the "Edit Top 200 Rows" window, you can click on the "SQL" toolbar button ("Show SQL Pane"), and it will expose the SQL query.  You can then modify the query (eg. add a where clause) so that you can filter down to only the records that you want to edit.

Of course, be careful with this (for all the reasons JNK mentioned) if you're editting the data manually.

Comment: Yes, I was basically looking for a shortcut to this mode of operation.